# reduce the cell background based on time swift

Tags: swift, iphone, uitableview, colors, cell

I would like to make sure that my cell has a background related to the remaining time. in the sense that the closer I get to 0, the more I would like it to be reduced, so that we understand that the timer is about to expire.

according to the elapsed time it automatically reduces from right to left.
this is the code I use in managing the Cell

[image: my cell now]

```
class TimerCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBInspectable var defaultBackgroundColor: UIColor = .white
@IBInspectable var runningBackgroundColor: UIColor = .white
@IBInspectable var pausedBackgroundColor: UIColor = .white

@IBInspectable var animationDuration: Double = 0

@IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var startButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var pauseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var stopButton: UIButton!

weak var timer: Timer? {
    didSet {
        guard let timer = timer else {
            updater?.invalidate()
            return
        }
        
        if case .running = timer.state {
            startUpdater()
        }
        
        configure(animated: false)
    }
}

private weak var updater: Foundation.Timer?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    print("*** \(Date()) setEditing(\(editing), animated: \(animated)) (timer?.name: \(String(describing: timer?.name)))")
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    configure(animated: animated)
}

func configure(animated: Bool = true) {
    guard let timer = timer else {
        return
    }
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animated ? animationDuration : 0) {
        guard !self.isEditing else {
            self.timeLabel.text = timer.initialTime.hmsString
            
            self.startButton.safelySetIsHidden(true)
            self.pauseButton.safelySetIsHidden(true)
            self.stopButton.safelySetIsHidden(true)
            
            self.backgroundColor = self.defaultBackgroundColor
            
            return
        }
        
        self.timeLabel.text = ceil(timer.timeForState).hmsString
        self.nameLabel.text = timer.name
        
        switch timer.state {
        case .stopped:
            self.stopButton.safelySetIsHidden(true)
            self.pauseButton.safelySetIsHidden(true)
            
            self.startButton.safelySetIsHidden(false)
            
            self.backgroundColor = self.defaultBackgroundColor
        case .running:
            self.startButton.safelySetIsHidden(true)
            
            self.stopButton.safelySetIsHidden( ceil(timer.timeForState) == 0 ? true : false )
            self.pauseButton.safelySetIsHidden( ceil(timer.timeForState) == 0 ? true : false )
            self.backgroundColor = self.runningBackgroundColor
            
        case .paused:
            self.pauseButton.safelySetIsHidden(true)
            
            self.startButton.safelySetIsHidden(false)
            self.stopButton.safelySetIsHidden(false)
            
            self.backgroundColor = self.pausedBackgroundColor
        }
    }
}

@IBAction private func startTimer() {
    timer?.state = .running
    configure()
    startUpdater()
}

@IBAction private func pauseTimer() {
    timer?.state = .paused
    configure()
}

@IBAction private func stopTimer() {
    timer?.state = .stopped
    configure()
}

private func startUpdater() {
    guard let timer = timer else {
        return
    }
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: timer.timeForState.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1))
    let updater = Foundation.Timer(fire: date, interval: 1, repeats: true) {
        [weak timer] updater in
        self.configure()
        if timer?.state != .running {
            updater.invalidate()
        }
    }
    self.updater = updater
    RunLoop.main.add(updater, forMode: .common)
}
```

}

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @matt I would like to put as a background to the cell the color that stitches up based on time

Comment: I do not know what "the color that stitches up based on time" means. If you want to change the cell background color, change it. Where is the code that does that? I don't see it.

Comment: @matt sorry which boils down I wanted to write..

Comment: The question remains. I don't see your code doing anything that would change the background color.

Comment: @matt sure, i didn't .. i have to set it but i don't know how to do it. to set a color all ok, but to make it rudurlo based on the remaining time how can I do?

Comment: You have to decide what "the remaining time" means, and you have to decide what "based on" means. A color is not a time. Exactly _how_ should the color change in relation to the remaining time? If the remaining time is 10 what color should it be? If the remaining time is 3 what color should it be? When you know that, just set the color. These are decisions that _you_ have to make.

Comment: @matt either I expressed myself badly or you didn't understand. suppose that the cell is red, now I want that if the set timer starts to start, as the timer runs, the color of the cell (red) decreases until it disappears when the timer reaches 0

Comment: What does it mean to "decrease" a color or "disappear" the color? Should it go from red to clear? From red to white? When you decide that, the problem is solved.

Comment: @matt reduce the cell capacity, half of the time will be half red and half white .. and so on

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that means. Can you draw a picture of what you want? When we are halfway through the time, what should the cell look like?

Comment: @matt https://files.fm/f/yuzy2ge5v#

Comment: Okay so that is not a simple background color. You are asking to draw a _gradient_ as the background _view_, and you will have to redraw that gradient each time the timer fires.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after something like this:

[image]

That's not trivial to achieve. I did it by adding a CAGradientLayer to the view and animating its `locations` property. At the same time, I ran the timer to change the label value.

So you might do it that way; you would probably want to tweak the values, of course. This is just a proof-of-concept demo.